Build fails when trying convert NextJS project using capacitorJS?
Been trying to convert a next js app to iOS app using capacitors JS. But it keeps throwing error during build process. I have cocoapods installed. Here's the error -
"✖ copy ios - failed!
[error] The web assets directory (./.next) must contain an index.html file.
It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.
[Ionic] Build Completed.
[error] /bin/sh: pod: command not found"
Here's the capacitor.config.js file -

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.unnamed',
  appName: 'unnamed',
  webDir: 'www'
};

export default config;

I've tried changing capacitor.config.js files webDir to
.next, build and www but it doesn't work
Here's next.config.js code (tried adding and removing output: export) -
module.exports = {
  output: 'export',
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'avatars.githubusercontent.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '**'
      }
    ]
  }


